# Overwrite AGOL feature services using a list

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

My ArcGIS Pro 2.8 project has 8 maps (e.g. *Tot Pop*, *11-14*, *0-18*, etc...), and they each have these three layers: *Elementary*, *Secondary* and *Unified*. What I've attempted is to iterate the maps. Then iterate each layer. Then get the layer by `lyr.name()`. From this point on, I'm stuck.

**GOAL:** I want to subsequently overwrite that layers' weblayer by using a counter that's tied to the list. The items in the list are the names of existing hosted feature services. For example, in the *Tot Pop* map, if the layer's name is *Elementary* grab `Elementary Tot Pop` from the list and use it to find the weblayer with the same name. Then overwrite it. I've left out the 'find and overwrite' part of the script for simplification.

```py
fs_names = ['Elementary Tot Pop', 'Secondary Tot Pop', 'Unified Tot Pop',
           'Elementary 11 to 14', 'Secondary 11 to 14', 'Unified 11 to 14',
           'Elementary 0 to 18', 'Secondary 0 to 18', 'Unified 0 to 18'...]

for prj in aprx.listMaps():
    print(f'--- Map: {prj.name} ---')
    for lyr in prj.listLayers():
        print(f'lyr: {lyr}')
        n = 0
        if lyr.name('Elementary'):
            overwrite0 = fs_names[n]
            print(overwrite0)
            #find and overwrite the weblayer here...
        elif lyr.name('Secondary'):
            overwrite1 = fs_names[n]
            print(overwrite1)
            #find and overwrite the weblayer here...
        elif lyr.name('Unified'):
            overwrite2 = fs_names[n]
            print(overwrite2)
            #find and overwrite the weblayer here...
            
        n += 1
```

What it prints out:

```
--- Map: Tot Pop ---
lyr: Elementary
Elementary Tot Pop
lyr: Secondary
Elementary Tot Pop
lyr: Unified
Elementary Tot Pop
--- Map: 11-14 ---
lyr: Elementary
Elementary Tot Pop
lyr: Secondary
Elementary Tot Pop
lyr: Unified
Elementary Tot Pop
--- Map: 0-18 ---
lyr: Elementary
Elementary Tot Pop
lyr: Secondary
Elementary Tot Pop
lyr: Unified
Elementary Tot Pop
```

What I want to see:

```
--- Map: Tot Pop ---
lyr: Elementary
Elementary Tot Pop
lyr: Secondary
Secondary Tot Pop
lyr: Unified
Unified Tot Pop
--- Map: 11-14 ---
lyr: Elementary
Elementary 11 to 14
lyr: Secondary
Secondary 11 to 14
lyr: Unified
Unified 11 to 14
--- Map: 0-18 ---
lyr: Elementary
Elementary 0 to 18
lyr: Secondary
Secondary 0 to 18
lyr: Unified
Unified 0 to 18
```

[This help doc](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000023164) does what I want one layer at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're resetting your `n=0` every loop, so it's always going to be the first value in the list.  Move `n=0` out of the for loop (put it above `for lyr in prj...`)

```
for prj in aprx.listMaps():
    print(f'--- Map: {prj.name} ---')
    n=0
    for lyr in prj.listLayers():
        print(f'lyr: {lyr}')
        if lyr.name('Elementary'):
            overwrite0 = fs_names[n]
            print(overwrite0)
            #find and overwrite the weblayer here...
        elif lyr.name('Secondary'):
            overwrite1 = fs_names[n]
            print(overwrite1)
            #find and overwrite the weblayer here...
        elif lyr.name('Unified'):
            overwrite2 = fs_names[n]
            print(overwrite2)
            #find and overwrite the weblayer here...
            
        n += 1
```

Comment: I had to move ```n = 0``` out of every loop, actually, to get what I want! So, it's above ```for prj in aprx.listMaps()```. But, you had the right idea.